# how to use Json in Python

Tags: django, json, python-2.7

How i can redo this code into Json

```
def getStatusData(self):
    return eval(self.__statusdata)

def setStatusData(self, statusdata):
    self.__statusdata = str(statusdata)

statusdata = property(getStatusData, setStatusData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

_data = {'someData': [1,2,3,4,5]}

jsoneddata = json.dumps(_data)
print jsoneddata
>>'{"someData": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}'


json.loads(jsoneddata)
>> {u'someData': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

[Official Python Documentation is here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

But, `getter` and `setter` functions are not encouraged in python. So simply :

```
self.__statusdata = json.dumps(statusdata)
statusdata = json.loads(self.__statusdata)
```

For your example, `eval` is a very dangerous way to use, unless you really know what it can cause and what you are doing. [More about eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function. Some wiki about [eval security risks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Security_risks)

Comment: +1 for the security risk of `eval`.